# Endless loop when restarting program with different parameters using Process.Start

Tags: .net, winforms, console-application, windows-server-2008, process.start

I rewrote a WinForms program to also be accessable and runnable via command line. On my Win10 machine everything works fine. Double clicking the executable runs the windowed version and calling it from the command line runs the command line version. Moreover I can explicitly set an option to ensure window or command line mode independent on how the executable was called.

The project is set as console application. To start the GUI version I close the console application and restart it without a console window.
The following code is the point where I do this.

```vb
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetConsoleWindow")>
Private Shared Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Init as GUI application by restarting.
''' This might be a little hacky, but there is no other way since otherwise command line input is not working properly. 
''' (I tried a lot variatons of attaching to the current cmd, etc.)
''' </summary>

Private Sub InitUI()
    Dim consoleHandle As IntPtr = GetConsoleWindow()
    If _configuration.IsGUIApplication And consoleHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        '' Restart without console, if it's a GUI application
        Dim binaryPath As String = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
        Dim processInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(binaryPath) With {
                  .CreateNoWindow = True,
                  .UseShellExecute = False,
                  .Arguments = Environment.CommandLine,
                  .WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(binaryPath)
            }

        Process.Start(processInfo)
        '' End current console process
        Environment.Exit(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem, that I now have is that this doesn't work on Windows Server 2008. If I start the application by double clicking nothing seems to happen. Looking into the TaskManager the program seems to call itself again and again, since the execution call is something like `Program.exe Program.exe, Program.exe Program.exe ...`

I assume that the `consoleHandle` is never `IntPtr.Zero`and therefore it's restarting and restarting and restarting.

I cannot debug on the Windows Server 2008, but I might add log messages to the program in doubt.
I tried some googling, but with no success right know.

**EDIT** My next step is to check whether the issue still happens, if avoid closing the current console application. In that case the window application should open and the console should run as background process.

=> I tried that now and it works. Nevertheless I would like to close the console application in the background such that only the window application is visible.

**EDIT 2** Just added some log messages and my assumption is true: The `consoleHandle` gets a new value on every restart and is never `IntPtr.Zero`

Does anyone have an idea?

**SOLUTION** I did not find the reason why Windows Server 2008 handles the issue differently than Win10. They way I solved it was to hide the console window instead of restarting the instance. I'm okay with that solution, but it means that I can't start the application from within a console without having the necessity to keep the console window open.

```vb
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetConsoleWindow")>
    Private Shared Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="ShowWindow")>
    Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
    Private Const SW_HIDE As Integer = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns whether the program was called from a console or not.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Private Function IsCalledFromConsole() As Boolean
        Dim left = Console.CursorLeft
        Dim top = Console.CursorTop
        Return Not (left = 0 AndAlso top = 0)
    End Function


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Init as GUI application by hiding the console window.
    ''' This might be a little hacky, but there is no other way since otherwise command line input is not working properly. 
    ''' (I tried a lot variatons of attaching to the current cmd, etc.!)
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub InitUI()
        Dim consoleHandle As IntPtr = GetConsoleWindow()

        If _configuration.IsGUIApplication And consoleHandle <> IntPtr.Zero And Not IsCalledFromConsole() Then
            ShowWindow(consoleHandle, SW_HIDE)
        End If

    End Sub
```